# Import javax.persistence cannot be resolved & Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Estoy migrando mis proyectos de Spring Boot desde un equipo viejo a uno nuevo e instalando versiones nuevas de los programas y me encuentro con este problema en los proyectos. Investigando en la web encontré algo relacionado con Jakarta pero no sé como implementarlo. Dejo una captura de Spring boot y las dependencias declaras en el archivo pom .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**pom.xml**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Por otro lado tengo un error un error para inicializar JPA. Dejo captura de la consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Si estás trabajando con Spring boot 3 debes cambiar los import de javax a jakarta, por ejemplo

```
import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Lob;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
```

Supongo que tienes la versión en el pom, ya que no compartiste la versión que estás ocupando, puedes mirarla en tu pom y te debería mostar la versión que ocupas, algo como esto, desde el 3.0 en adelante hay que cambiar los imports de javax a jakarta

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: Se solucionó lo de la importación cambiando por jakarta pero ahora tengo problema para inicializar jpa. También agregué en el pom la versión que estoy usando